# Suppose that $\ln(f(t))= t f(t)$. What is $\lim f'(t)$ as $t \to 0^+$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $\ln(f(t))= t × f(t)$, what is $\lim f'(t)$ as $t$ goes to $0$ from the positive side?
Using implicit derivative, I got that $f'(t)=\frac{f(t)^2}{1-tf(t)}$.
But i got a bit confused while calculating the limit. It's obvious That $f(0)=1$, so is the limit equal to $1$ or to $-\infty$?

Comment: Why would the limit equal $-\infty$?

Comment: Beause i think limit of f(t) is $\infty$ , and using the L'Hospital rule we get that limit of f'(x) is -$\infty$. But i'm not sure.

Comment: You've made a superb observation : the point is that if $f$ is defined so that $\frac{\ln f(t)}{f(t)} = t$, then $f$ isn't actually well-defined : for example, at $t = 0.1$, you have two values $\sim 1,35$ that could be $f(t)$. So there are two "branches" of $f$, one going to $1$ and the other to $\infty$. It isn't "obvious" that $f(0)$ is even defined : If it were true that $f(0)=1$ and $f$ is continuous at zero, then the limit is $1$. Otherwise, it's fair to say there isn't an answer.